Is there any use for an algorithm that converts a 3-CNF expression into a mathematical expression using Fourier series approximations?
I wrote a program to convert the 3-CNF satisfiablity problem into a mathematical one using Fourier series approximations.
https://github.com/powertech2718/cnf2fourier
For example,
(v1 | v2 | v3) & (v1 | !v2 | v3) & (!v1 | !v2 | !v3) 

turns into this long equation
f(x) := (-(-I*exp(9*I*pi*x/4)/(9*pi) - I*exp(7*I*pi*x/4)/(7*pi) - I*exp(5*I*pi*x/4)/(5*pi)- I*exp(3*I*pi*x/4)/(3*pi) - I*exp(I*pi*x/4)/pi + 1/2 + I*exp(-I*pi*x/4)/pi + I*exp(-3*I*pi*x/4)/(3*pi) + I*exp(-5*I*pi*x/4)/(5*pi) + I*exp(-7*I*pi*x/4)/(7*pi) + I*exp(-9*I*pi*x/4)/(9*pi))*(-I*exp(9*I*pi*x/2)/(9*pi) - I*exp(7*I*pi*x/2)/(7*pi) - I*exp(5*I*pi*x/2)/(5*pi) - I*exp(3*I*pi*x/2)/(3*pi) - I*exp(I*pi*x/2)/pi + 1/2 + I*exp(-I*pi*x/2)/pi + I*exp(-3*I*pi*x/2)/(3*pi) + I*exp(-5*I*pi*x/2)/(5*pi) + I*exp(-7*I*pi*x/2)/(7*pi) + I*exp(-9*I*pi*x/2)/(9*pi))*(-I*exp(9*I*pi*x)/(9*pi) - I*exp(7*I*pi*x)/(7*pi) - I*exp(5*I*pi*x)/(5*pi) - I*exp(3*I*pi*x)/(3*pi) - I*exp(I*pi*x)/pi + 1/2 + I*exp(-I*pi*x)/pi + I*exp(-3*I*pi*x)/(3*pi) + I*exp(-5*I*pi*x)/(5*pi) + I*exp(-7*I*pi*x)/(7*pi) + I*exp(-9*I*pi*x)/(9*pi)) + 1)*(-(-I*exp(9*I*pi*x/4)/(9*pi) - I*exp(7*I*pi*x/4)/(7*pi) - I*exp(5*I*pi*x/4)/(5*pi) - I*exp(3*I*pi*x/4)/(3*pi) - I*exp(I*pi*x/4)/pi + 1/2 + I*exp(-I*pi*x/4)/pi + I*exp(-3*I*pi*x/4)/(3*pi) + I*exp(-5*I*pi*x/4)/(5*pi) + I*exp(-7*I*pi*x/4)/(7*pi) + I*exp(-9*I*pi*x/4)/(9*pi))*(I*exp(9*I*pi*x/2)/(9*pi) + I*exp(7*I*pi*x/2)/(7*pi) + I*exp(5*I*pi*x/2)/(5*pi) + I*exp(3*I*pi*x/2)/(3*pi) + I*exp(I*pi*x/2)/pi + 1/2 - I*exp(-I*pi*x/2)/pi - I*exp(-3*I*pi*x/2)/(3*pi) - I*exp(-5*I*pi*x/2)/(5*pi) - I*exp(-7*I*pi*x/2)/(7*pi) - I*exp(-9*I*pi*x/2)/(9*pi))*(-I*exp(9*I*pi*x)/(9*pi) - I*exp(7*I*pi*x)/(7*pi) - I*exp(5*I*pi*x)/(5*pi) - I*exp(3*I*pi*x)/(3*pi) - I*exp(I*pi*x)/pi + 1/2 + I*exp(-I*pi*x)/pi + I*exp(-3*I*pi*x)/(3*pi) + I*exp(-5*I*pi*x)/(5*pi) + I*exp(-7*I*pi*x)/(7*pi) + I*exp(-9*I*pi*x)/(9*pi)) + 1)*(-(I*exp(9*I*pi*x/4)/(9*pi) + I*exp(7*I*pi*x/4)/(7*pi) + I*exp(5*I*pi*x/4)/(5*pi) + I*exp(3*I*pi*x/4)/(3*pi) + I*exp(I*pi*x/4)/pi + 1/2 - I*exp(-I*pi*x/4)/pi - I*exp(-3*I*pi*x/4)/(3*pi) - I*exp(-5*I*pi*x/4)/(5*pi) - I*exp(-7*I*pi*x/4)/(7*pi) - I*exp(-9*I*pi*x/4)/(9*pi))*(I*exp(9*I*pi*x/2)/(9*pi) + I*exp(7*I*pi*x/2)/(7*pi) + I*exp(5*I*pi*x/2)/(5*pi) + I*exp(3*I*pi*x/2)/(3*pi) + I*exp(I*pi*x/2)/pi + 1/2 - I*exp(-I*pi*x/2)/pi - I*exp(-3*I*pi*x/2)/(3*pi) - I*exp(-5*I*pi*x/2)/(5*pi) - I*exp(-7*I*pi*x/2)/(7*pi) - I*exp(-9*I*pi*x/2)/(9*pi))*(I*exp(9*I*pi*x)/(9*pi) + I*exp(7*I*pi*x)/(7*pi) + I*exp(5*I*pi*x)/(5*pi) + I*exp(3*I*pi*x)/(3*pi) + I*exp(I*pi*x)/pi + 1/2 - I*exp(-I*pi*x)/pi - I*exp(-3*I*pi*x)/(3*pi) - I*exp(-5*I*pi*x)/(5*pi) - I*exp(-7*I*pi*x)/(7*pi) - I*exp(-9*I*pi*x)/(9*pi)) + 1)

Graph of the formula f(x)
The purpose of this is to perform symbolic calculus operations on the formula like integration and root finding to find the variable assignments for 3-CNF satisfiability.
Specifically for integration,
using the above $f(x)$, where $x$ ranging from 0 to $2^k -1$ is the bit-wise assignment of variables indexed at 0.  If $f(x)$ is ~ 1 then those variable assignments will make the 3-CNF true and ~ 0 will make it false. (3-CNF satisfiability). The integral of f(x) from $[a,b)$ gives the number of solutions between the integral range and then doing a binary search for the solution at the takes O(k) * O(cost of integral evaluation) + O(cost of integral finding).
The problem is that Python's sympy is very slow computing the integral for any values of $n>2$ (referring Fourier series summation $n$) and a trivial number of 3-CNF clauses (3).  I am afraid it is trying to expand and exploding combinatorially somewhere.  maxima and Mathematica are faster but similar.
If symbolic methods prove to be unfeasible, is there any use for this conversion program besides being interesting?
Are there any numerical root finding or integration methods that work well with this highly periodic functions like the one listed?
